# represent a number as sum of four positive integer 1<a<=b<=c<=d

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Given N=a+b+c+d where a,b,c,d are positive integers greater than 0 and a<=b<=c<=d.

We have to count the number of ways to express N as sum of 4 such numbers.

My approach is to have four loops and add them to n .
But time complexity will be O(n^4) 
Can we reduce it ?

Comment: Plugging the first set of numbers from a brute-force implementation into [The Only Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org) gave me these two links: [Number of partitions of n into at most 4 parts](https://oeis.org/A001400) and [Number of partitions of n in which the greatest part is 4](https://oeis.org/A026810).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1. How many ways are there to represent N as a sum of two numbers, a & b? Call this S2(N).
2. Can you work out how many ways there are to represent N as a sum of three numbers, a, b & c? (Use S2() in your answer)? Call this S3(N).

   > Start by considering S3(100), and count the number of possibilities where the largest number (c) is 97; then count the possibilities for 96, 95 etc. This works for c>50, but breaks down then because of double-counting some possibilities. Can you fix this by adding a parameter to S2() and S3() to control the largest number in the sum?
3. Now, how many ways are there to represent N as a sum of four numbers, a, b,  c & d? (Use S3() in your answer).

Comment: please elaborate , i am not able to understand

Comment: What is the answer to the first question?

Comment: To represent N as a sum of two numbers where `0 < a <= b` is `n / 2` using integer division. How this can be expanded to cover 3 or 4 I have no idea. Please enlighten us.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: OK, so `S2(N)=int(n/2).` Now take the example of N=100 and look for a+b+c=100. The highest possible value of c is 98. How many values for a&b are there when c=98? When c=97? When c=X (X>50)?

Comment: (Things get trickier for smaller c, because you have to avoid collisions with the other numbers, in order to avoid double-counting; at this stage it's necessary to introduce another parameter, so we'd want to tweak our definition of S2 to be S2(N, L) = number of ways of using 2 positive integers less than L to sum to N; this approach should hopefully lead to a recurrence that can be evaluated in time better than O(n^5) using memoisation or similar)

Comment: (Actually it seems to work better to have Sk(N, L)  = number of ways of using k positive integers to sum to L where the greatest integer used is exactly L)